# How to install MongoDB & Its driver for Windows 10 (Step by Step)?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, php, mongodb

I want to install MongoDB & MongoDB Driver for Windows 10 ... There are many version of MongoDB that I don't know which version is proper for Windows 10. I downloaded one of them & It works, when I download the proper Driver for that & Adding the Extension for PHP, I doesn't work. My PHP Version is 5.5, Thread Safe & x64. So I came here to ask Can anyone help me which version I should download for Windows 10 & Its proper driver ?

PHP Version 5.5.12

Architecture    x64

Thread Safety   enabled

Comment: The operating system doesn't really matter. It's just "PHP 5.5 Threadsafe x64 on Windows" that matters. Also, PHP 5.5 is outdated. You should consider upgrading.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks, But can you tell me which one is the most suitable for Windows 10 ? Because I don't know why It doesn't Intsall ..., I have Installed one of them & It was 3.2, So I went to this page (https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) & I downloaded 1.1.8, PHP 5.5, Thread Safe, x64 ...

Comment: What exactly did you download? The DLL? How did you “install” it? What happened? Did you reference the DLL in `php.ini`?